# Using mocking with apply R

Tags: r, unit-testing, mocking, apply

I am currently mocking in some unit tests, using the packages `testthat`and `mockery`. I am trying to understand how the function `expect_args`from the `mockery`package works when the mocked function is actually called in a function using `apply`. Here is an example where the test is successful.

```
myMean <- function(A){
 apply(A,1,mean)
}

myMat = matrix(rep(1,6), nrow = 2, ncol = 3)
test_that("myMean calls base::mean correctly",{
 m <- mock(1, cycle = TRUE)
 with_mock(
 `base::mean` = m,
  myMean(myMat),
  expect_args(m, 1, as.double(myMat[1,])))
})
```

Let's take now a slightly more complicated example, where the argument of `myMean`is actually a `data.frame` and needs to be converted to a matrix within the function.

```
myMean <- function(A){
 B = as.matrix(A)
 apply(B,1,mean)
}

myMat = as.data.frame(myMat)
test_that("myMean calls base::mean correctly",{
m <- mock(1, cycle = TRUE)
with_mock(
 `base::mean` = m,
  myMean(myMat),
 expect_args(m, 1, as.double(myMat[1,])))
})
```

I then get the following error message:

```
Error: Test failed: 'myMeanSimple calls base::mean correct number of times         
* 1st actual argument not equal to 1st expected argument.
names for target but not for current
```

This error is explained on the [vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mockery/vignettes/mocks-and-testthat.html) of the `mockery` package. Nevertheless I do not manage to find which argument name I should associate with `as.double(myMat[1,])`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, I'm happy this small utility became useful! Second of all, the error you see results from how your transformations are carried out and how `expect_args` compares results. Internally, we call `expect_equal` which requires all of the names of the `matrix` to be present there.

After calling your second example I run this:

```
> mock_args(m)
[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
V1 V2 V3 
 1  1  1 

[[2]]
[[2]][[1]]
V1 V2 V3 
 1  1  1
```

So you can see that in the first call a single *named* raw was passed, and the same is true for the second call - there are *names* assigned to each column. This is because `as.matrix` preserves column names. So this is not about *argument* names, this is about names in the *data* that's compared.

Now, when you run your final comparison using `expect_args` you actually use `as.double` which doesn't preserve names. Thus, the error you see. To fix it you can simply change your expectation to:

```
expect_args(m, 1, as.matrix(myMat)[1,])
```

I hope this solves your problem.

Comment: Yes it does. Thank you very much.